# Antd Timepicker set defaultValue from variable

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

As per their [Timepicker](https://ant.design/components/time-picker) library i did following in React:

```
<TimePicker defaultValue={moment(dbTime1, format)} format={format}
onChange={time => setStartTime(moment(time).format(format))}/>
```

the state is:

```
const [dbTime1, setDbTime1] = useState("");
const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(new Date());
```

Reading from database the string value 09:00 with:

```
setDbTime1(moment(timeWindowsData.din_times_for_rep[0].val));
```

The problem that the visual part is not displaying required to me 09:00 time, it just offering to select a time. If I do some modifications to the formats, etc - it gaves me various errors. Starting from invalid date and finishing with ipossibility to select a time, falling back to Date(), etc.

How can I store the variable and display the time in time field as default value?

It's working if i just drop the string there:

```
<TimePicker defaultValue={"09:00", format)} format={format}
onChange={time => setStartTime(moment(time).format(format))}/>
```

But I need that it must read from variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed this component and used the other ones.